# StatusBar is not abstract and does not override abstract method onPreferenceChange

Tags: java, android, statusbar, rom

I'm working on a custom ROM and I'm receiving this error while trying to compile it. I tried to add a custom battery selector.

```
com.android.settings.pcf.StatusBar is not abstract and does not override abstract method onPreferenceChange(android.preference.Preference,java.lang.Object) in android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
```

This is the the com.android.settings.pcf.StatusBar file:

```
package com.android.settings.pcf;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.provider.Settings;

import com.android.settings.SettingsPreferenceFragment;
import com.android.settings.R;

public class StatusBar extends SettingsPreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String PREF_BATT_ICON = "battery_icon_list";

    ListPreference mBatteryIcon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_statusbar);

        mBatteryIcon = (ListPreference) findPreference(PREF_BATT_ICON);
        mBatteryIcon.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mBatteryIcon.setValue((Settings.System.getInt(getActivity()
                .getContentResolver(), Settings.System.STATUSBAR_BATTERY_ICON,
                0))
                + "");
    }

    public boolean OnPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (preference == mBatteryIcon) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt((String) newValue);
            return Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.STATUSBAR_BATTERY_ICON, val);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you didn't fully implement the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` interface. In particular, the `onPreferenceChange` method is not implemented.

Either implement this method, or I'm actually guessing you meant `OnPreferenceChange` to be `onPreferenceChange` - note the lowercase "o" - (in which case I believe you will also need a `@Override` before it)

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe that I didn't notice the capital o. I changed it to a lowercase and added @Override and it works now. Thanks a bunch.